# Espresso - how to access child elements of ViewHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-espresso

[image]

For the given RecyclerView, I can access the LinearLayout element by:

```
recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(1)
```

Where 1 is the 2nd element/position within RecyclerView and the ViewHolder is returned.

How can I then access the child elements of the ViewHolder LinearLayout? Or is there a way to get to the AppCompatTextView element so that I can pull the text from that element?

Answer (score 0):

> I have created RecyclerViewMatcher class then following code

```html
onView(withRecyclerView(R.id.rv_fragment_recipes).atPosition(0))
                .check(matches(isDisplayed()));

        onView(withRecyclerView(R.id.rv_fragment_recipes).atPositionOnView(0, R.id.tv_recipe_name))
                .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
                .check(matches(withText("Nutella Pie")));

        onView(withRecyclerView(R.id.rv_fragment_recipes).atPositionOnView(0, R.id.tv_servings))
                .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
                .check(matches(withText("Servings : 8")));

        onView(withRecyclerView(R.id.rv_fragment_recipes).atPosition(0))
                .perform(click());
```

```html
public class RecyclerViewMatcher {
    private final int recyclerViewId;

    public RecyclerViewMatcher(int recyclerViewId) {
        this.recyclerViewId = recyclerViewId;
    }

    public Matcher<View> atPosition(final int position) {
        return atPositionOnView(position, -1);
    }

    public Matcher<View> atPositionOnView(final int position, final int targetViewId) {

        return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
            Resources resources = null;
            View childView;

            public void describeTo(Description description) {
                String idDescription = Integer.toString(recyclerViewId);
                if (this.resources != null) {
                    try {
                        idDescription = this.resources.getResourceName(recyclerViewId);
                    } catch (Resources.NotFoundException var4) {
                        idDescription = String.format("%s (resource name not found)",
                                new Object[] { Integer.valueOf
                                        (recyclerViewId) });
                    }
                }

                description.appendText("with id: " + idDescription);
            }

            public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {

                this.resources = view.getResources();

                if (childView == null) {
                    RecyclerView recyclerView =
                            (RecyclerView) view.getRootView().findViewById(recyclerViewId);
                    if (recyclerView != null && recyclerView.getId() == recyclerViewId) {
                        childView = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position).itemView;
                    }
                    else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                if (targetViewId == -1) {
                    return view == childView;
                } else {
                    View targetView = childView.findViewById(targetViewId);
                    return view == targetView;
                }

            }
        };
    }
}
```

[for refernce you can follow this project](https://github.com/akshay3015/yummy_bakingApp_udacity/blob/master/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/android/bakingapp/IdlingResourceMainActivityTest.java)

> Use IdelingResource if recyclerView data is not static

Comment: Yeah, i have seen this code.  This will get you to the ViewHolder element as described in my question, but is there a way to get the child elements of that, to get directly to the text element shown?  This code does not currently do that.